# Python: Adding excel file to an access database

Tags: python, excel, ms-access, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to access an access (accdb) file. I want to add an excel workbook into the access database programatically, but cannot find an API to do so. Here is my current code:

```
import pyodbc
DBFile = r'C:\Documents and Settings\IA.accdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBFile)

exFile = r'C:\Documents and Settings\IA_2006.xls'
conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver \ 
                       (*.xls)};DBQ='+exFile,autocommit=True)

cursor = conn.cursor()
####IA_1 is a table within IA.accdb
cursor.execute('select * from IA_1')
row = cursor.fetchone()
####For debugging, print a line
if row:
        print row
```

How should I import the data from the excel file (IA_2006.xls) into the IA.accdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you got to a certain point and gave up.
Don't give up! :-)

You've made the connection to the Excel spreadsheet, now you need to read it*.

```
curs1 = conn1.cursor()
# the following returns list of tuples
excel_results = curs1.execute('select [a_column]
                               from [Sheet1$]').fetchall()
```

Then you can insert to your MS Access db, e.g.:

```
curs.executemany('insert into mytable (mycolumn) values (?)', excel_results)
conn.commit()
```

*If in doubt, Excel sheet names can be found by running the following:

```
for row in curs1.tables():
    print row.table_name
```